# Segmentation fault 11 in C++ on Mac HighSierra

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, queue

It gets segmentation fault 11 when I tried to inqueue the data in my queue program. I'm using the GCC compiler in my Atom text editor.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5

using namespace std;

struct queue{
    int data[MAX];
    int awal, akhir;
}antrean;

void first(){
    antrean.awal = -1;
    antrean.akhir = -1;
}

bool isfull(){
    if(antrean.akhir == MAX-1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

bool isempty(){
    if(antrean.akhir == -1){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

void tampildata(){
    if(!isempty()){
        for(int i=antrean.awal; i<antrean.akhir; i++){
            cout<<antrean.data[i]<<" | ";
        }
    }

    cout<<endl;
}

void inqueue(){
    int elemen;

    if(isempty()){
        cout<<"input data : ";
        cin>>elemen;
        antrean.data[antrean.akhir] = elemen;
        antrean.akhir++;
        cout<<"data berhasil ditambah"<<endl;
        tampildata();
    }else{
        cout<<"Queue penuh";
    }
}


void dequeue(){
    tampildata();

    if(!isempty()){
        cout<<"mengambil data "<<antrean.data[antrean.awal]<<endl;

        for(int i=antrean.awal; i<antrean.akhir; i++){
            antrean.data[i]=antrean.data[i+1];
        }

        antrean.akhir--;
    }else{
        cout<<"antrean empty";
    }
}

void cari(){
    if(!isempty() == 1){
        int cari;
        bool state = false;
        cout << "Data yang dicari :";
        cin >> cari;

        for(int i = antrean.awal; i<antrean.akhir; i++){
            if (antrean.data[i] == cari) {
                cout << "Data ditemukan pada indeks Ke-:" << antrean.data[i]+1<< endl;
                state = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } else{
        cout << "Data tidak ditemukan";
    }
}

void totalarray(){
    int temp = 0;

    for(int i=-1; i<antrean.akhir; i++){
        temp = temp+antrean.data[i];
    }

    cout << "Total nilainya :" << temp;
}

int main(){
    int pilihan, elemen;
    first();

    do{
        tampildata();
        cout<<"1. Init"<<endl<<"2. inQueue"<<endl<<"3. deQueue"<<endl<<"4. tampil data"<<endl<<"5. Cari data"<<endl << "6. Total nilai"<<endl<<"7. Rata-rata Array"<<endl;
        cout<<"8. Nilai terbesar"<<endl<<"9. Nilai terkecil"<<endl<<"10. Clear"<<endl<<"11. Keluar";
        cout<<"input pilihan :";
        cin>>pilihan;

        switch(pilihan){
            case 1:
                first();
                break;
            case 2:
                inqueue();
                break;
            case 3:
                dequeue();
                break;
            case 4:
                tampildata();
                break;
            case 5:
                cari();
                break;
            case 6:
                totalarray();
                break;
            case 7:
                exit(0);
        }
    }

    while(pilihan!=7);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome bro. You should read the first chapter of any programming book, so that you can understand how to write a code, like indentation and other things.

Comment: This looks much too long. Also, adding indentation would help make this easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in the value of your counter. You initially set it to -1 (although 0 might make more sense if it has 0 elements?). Then, when you're adding to your queue for the first time you basically want to add an element to the (-1)st place. This causes you to write outside the bounds of the array and a segmentation fault occurs.

```
antrean.akhir = -1;
...
antrean.data[antrean.akhir] = elemen;
```

You can simply set the counter to 0 and have it actually count the number of elements in the array.

I have not gone through the rest of the code, so I can't say it won't crash for some other reason later on.